# If "multiples" is to "product", "_____" is to "sum"

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

I know this might be a really simple question for those fluent in English, but I can't find the term that describes numbers that make up a sum.

The numbers of a certain product are called "multiples" of that "product". 
Then what are the numbers of a certain sum called?

Comment: Does summands work? Maybe this is of help also ;) http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summand

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that I don't think I've ever heard the numbers occurring in a product described as multiples before. I'm not in fact sure what they are usually called - factors is probably a decent name.

Comment: Agree with Matt. I would suggest "factors" and "terms", but English is not my first language.

Comment: One of my maths dictionaries has multiplicator and multiplicand, but I've never seen either used in practice.

Comment: In $12 = 3 \times 4$, we say $12$ is the product and $3$ and $4$ are factors.  In some situations we may specify one of $3,4$ as the multiplier, and the other as the multiplicand.  Similarly: in $7 = 3 + 4$, we say $7$ is the sum and $3$ and $4$ are terms or summands.

Comment: I prefer 'terms' but in practice tend to use 'thingamabob', 'doohickey', and 'whatchamacallit' as a catchall to describe something I can't think of the name of.

Comment: @nofe: Funny you said you can't find the *term*... ;-)

Comment: I rolled back the edits. The OP doesn't speak English, so why not leave his original (fully understandable) wording and avoid orphaning a bunch of comments?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition#Notation_and_terminology), "summands", "addends", or "terms" are all acceptable.

Also, I've never heard "multiples" used as the corresponding word for multiplication. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Notation_and_terminology) lists the words "factors" and "multiplicands" both of which I'm familiar with.

Comment: nofe, I voted for this answer because it also clears-up the terminology for "factors"...

Comment: additionally one could mention that "multiples" of a number $x$ usually refers to all $n x$ with some $n\in\mathbb{K}$ (often $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @TheChaz cool. (btw, what do these votes actually do?)

Comment: They are for [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)

Comment: *Terms* is by far the most common in my experience.  *Summands* is rare, and I've never heard *addends* used in practice.

Comment: To some extent it depends on whether you're thinking about the expression in itself or the process of evaluating the expression.  Thus $x$ and $y$ are the terms of the expression $x + y$ and the factors of the expression $xy$, but in a discussion of algorithms for addition or multiplication you might speak of addends or multiplicands.

Answer (score 7):

To approach the question from another direction: A "multiple" of 7 is a number that is the result of multiplying 7 with something else.

If your try to generalize that to sums, you get something like: A "**__**" of 7 is a number that is the result of adding 7 to something. But that's everything -- at least as long as we allow negative numbers, and if we *don't* allow negative numbers, then it just means something that is larger than 7. Neither of these concepts feel useful enough in themselves that it is worth it deciding on a particular noun for it.

Answer (score 2):

"Summands"

$\phantom{\text{(hmm, first time MSE says my answer is too short; P.S., added by mixedmath: either this or adding empty sets is a good way to add to the length ;p)}}$

${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I edited your answer, because I think this was the desired effect you were going for. Right?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is addend.  a number that is added to another. "as its name suggests, the Accumulator ‘accumulates’ by keeping its addend in memory and incrementing by the addend it receives from another transmitting unit"