# "summand" is to "sum" $\left(\sum\right)$ as ___ is to "product" $\left(\prod\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, math-history

(Not a duplicate of [If "multiples" is to "product", "_____" is to "sum"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130093/if-multiples-is-to-product-is-to-sum))

When working with sums or series, I often refer to $a_n$ in the summation $\sum\limits_n a_n$ as the "summand". **Is there an analogous word for $b_n$ in the product $\prod\limits_n b_n$?**

Wikipedia's description of ["summation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) makes several mentions of $a_n$ as the "summand" or "addend", but no equivalent is provided in the article on ["product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(mathematics)). My guess would be "multiplicand", but there appears to be a consistent definition ([1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multiplicand), [2](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiplicand.html), [3](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiplicand)) for it as referring to a specific number in a product. To paraphrase,

> In the product $a\times b$, we call $b$ the "multiplicand" and $a$ the "multiplier".

I've also found that

- in the sum $a+b$, ["summand"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summand) could refer to either $a$ or $b$; ["addend"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/addend) can be used interchangeably with "summand"
- in the difference $a-b$, $a$ is the ["minuend"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minuend) and $b$ is the ["subtrahend"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subtrahend)
- in the quotient $\frac ab$, $a$ is the ["dividend"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dividend) and $b$ is the ["divisor"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divisor)
- if $\star$ is an arbitrary binary operator, ["operand"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/operand) works like "summand" and can refer to either $a$ or $b$ in the expression $a\star b$

as summarized in this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Arithmetic_operations).

"Summand" and "addend" being treated as synonymous almost mirrors the commutativity of $+$, but I suspect this is not the reason for their interchangeability. ***Optional*: Is there a historical/etymological reason for making the distinction between the "multiplicand" $a$ and "multiplier" $b$ in $a\times b$, as well as the other operations listed above?**

(The latter question may be more appropriate for the math history or English/Latin language SE's)

Comment: I've never heard of "multiplicand" and "multiplier" in this context. As for the question in the title, the answer should be "factor".

Comment: Language evolves.  The specific words you allude to are often-times considered un-useful and unnecessary...  It is far more common in modern language to simply refer to them with generic language as "terms in a product" or "terms in a sum."

Comment: @Thorgott I see, I was focusing on seeking out a "-cand" word and didn't notice "factor" in the first sentence of the "Product" article

Comment: factor or term, both suffice

Comment: I have heard multiplicand before. Its meaning is entirely clear from just reading it (it is an object that's being multiplied with, like summand is something that's being summed, integrand is something being integrated, and presumably many more), so I see no issue with it apart from it being somewhat uncommon.

Comment: In addition ($a+b$), one sometimes distinguishes the *augend* ($a$) from the *addend* ($b$). Taken literally, an augend is a thing that is "going to be enlarged", and an addend is a thing that is "going to be bestowed".

Comment: [product of (a sequence of) factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Product_of_a_sequence)